# LINQ GroupBy DateTime dilemma

Tags: linq, ef-code-first

I have the following code:

```
public IDictionary<string, int> GetCountByDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    var result = Database.Set<User>().Where(x => x.CreatedAt >= fromDate && x.CreatedAt <= toDate).GroupBy(x => new { x.CreatedAt.Year, x.CreatedAt.Month, x.CreatedAt.Day }).Select(x => new { Date = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });

    return result.ToDictionary(x => new DateTime(x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month, x.Date.Day).ToShortDateString(), x => x.Count);
}
```

This code works perfectly well but the problem is that the DateTime is stored as UTC in the database. The moment I do the GroupBy operation I lose the Time part. So if I tried to convert it back to loca time with the following:

```
return result.ToDictionary(x => new DateTime(x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month, x.Date.Day).ToLocalTime().ToShortDateString(), x => x.Count);
```

It would be based on a different time and therefore incorrect. The column has to stay DateTime.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do... are you trying to group UTC-stored dates based on the local time of the server running .NET? That sounds unlikely to be a good idea, to be honest.

Comment: Since I am storing everything as UTC in the database, I want to display a count of users grouped by date but the date should be in local time. The reason is if a user signs up at 10/28 9pm EST time, he actually signed up 10/29 2am GMT time. The current code would attribute that count to the 29th for everyone. What I am trying to accomplish is that a user on eastern time would see that user attributed to the 28th. Am I making any sense?

Comment: But that's talking about the *user's* time zone, not the time zone of the server. If you *do* make it work on varying time zones, then different people will get different results, which doesn't sound great either. If you're interested in when people signed up in *their* local time, then you should store it in their local time instead of in UTC.

Comment: Jon, sorry my mistake. You were right the first time. I am trying to group UTC-stored dates based on the local time of the server. Is this a bad idea? If so, why?

Comment: The local time of the server is rarely a *useful* thing to be interested in. Why would I care where the server is? What business-related meaning does it have where I choose to host the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the real challenge is that you'll need to translate twice. First, taking the local DateTime you're feeding into the method (your question only makes sense if those are local) need to be translated into UTC for the query. But then you need to translate x.CreatedAt into local before you do your grouping—on the server, in other words. This is tricky, but works if you use the SqlFunctions library in System.Data.Objects.SqlClient. Here's what it'd look like. Messy and I don't know how performant it'd be, but it should work.

```
public IDictionary<string, int> GetCountByDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate) 
{ 
    DateTime utcFrom = fromDate.ToUniversalTime();
    DateTime utcTo = toDate.ToUniversalTime();
    int offset = (int)(fromDate - utcFrom).TotalHours;
    var result = Database.Set<User>().Where(x => x.CreatedAt >= utcFrom && x.CreatedAt <= utcTo)
        .GroupBy(x => new { 
            SqlFunctions.DateAdd("hh", offset, x.CreatedAt).Value.Year, 
            SqlFunctions.DateAdd("hh", offset, x.CreatedAt).Value.Month, 
            SqlFunctions.DateAdd("hh", offset, x.CreatedAt).Value.Day })
        .Select(x => new { Date = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });

    return result.ToDictionary(x => new DateTime(x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month, x.Date.Day).ToShortDateString(), x => x.Count); 
}
```

At that point, the date values in your dictionary object are already in local time, so no need to convert them for presentation.